# Let $A ⊆ E ⊆ R$, where $E$ is measurable and $A$ is non-measurable. Prove that $m^∗ (E − A) > 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have been asked to prove a statement-
Let $A ⊆ E ⊆ R$, where $E$ is measurable and $A$ is non-measurable. Prove that $m^∗
(E − A) > 0$.

I used the Caratheordory criterion-
For a measurable set $E$ and any set $A⊆ R$
$$m^∗(A) = m^∗(A ∩ E)+m^∗(A ∩ E^c)$$

Now $m^∗(A) = m^∗(A ∩ E)$ which gives that $m^∗(A ∩ E^c)=0$

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that $A\cap E^c$ is $A-E$, not $E-A$; $E-A$ would be $E\cap A^c$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I dont understand, is'nt intersection a commutative operation?

Comment: $A \cap B=B\cap A$ but that does not mean $A^{c} \cap B=B^{c}\cap A$.

Comment: $A\cap E^c$ is the same thing as $E^c\cap A$, but not as $E\cap A^c$. $A\cap E^c$ are the things in $A$ that are not in $E$, so $A-E$. $A^c\cap E$ are the things in $E$ that are not in $A$, so $E-A$. In fact, $A\cap E^c=A-E$ is *disjoint* from $E-A=E\cap A^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that measurable here means Lebesgue measurable.

> Let $A \subseteq E \subseteq \Bbb R$, where $E$ is measurable and $A$ is non-measurable. Then $m^∗ (E − A) > 0$.

**Proof**:  Since $A \subseteq E$, we have that $A=E-(E-A)$.

If $m^∗(E − A) = 0$ then $E- A$ is measurable and then $A$ is measurable.

Since  $m^∗ (E − A) \geqslant 0$, by the counter-positive, if $A$ is non-measurable, then $m^∗ (E − A) > 0$.